# Closing the Tweets - CodeChef

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Can someone please tell me as to why I'm getting WA for the following solution on CodeChef?

Link for the problem: https://www.codechef.com/problems/TWTCLOSE

Solution:

```
n, k = map(int, input().split()) 
com = [] 
while(k):
    k -= 1
    com.append(input()) 
l = len(com) 
tweets = [] 
for i in range(0, n):
    tweets.append(False) 
for i in range(0, l):
    if(com[i] == "CLOSEALL"):
        for j in range(0, n):
            tweets[j] = False
    else:
        temp = com[i]
        tweets[int(temp[-1])-1] = not tweets[int(temp[-1])-1]
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        if(tweets[i]):
            count += 1
    print(count)
```

Input:

```
3 6
CLICK 1
CLICK 2
CLICK 3
CLICK 2
CLOSEALL
CLICK 1
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
2
0
1
```

Comment: What's "WA"? Also, please post your code as `formatted text` and explain what the problem is.

Comment: Probably 'wrong answer'?

Comment: WA is Wrong Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, l):
    tweets.append(False)
```

This is wrong, there are N tweets, l is just the amount of clicks.

```
if(com[i] == "CLOSEALL"):
    for j in range(0, l):
        tweets[j] = False
```

Wrong for same reason.

```
for i in range(0, l):
    if(tweets[i]):
        count += 1
```

Again, only counting up to l instead of N. In fact, you never use n at all. That is a big hint you are missing something.

**Update after your corrections:**

```
tweets[int(temp[-1])-1] = not tweets[int(temp[-1])-1]
```

temp[-1] means the last character, which is all good for clicking tweets from 1 to 9, but if you want to click tweet 21, you are just picking last char so you click tweet 1 instead of 21. Making a split by space and picking all the digits would be a way to fix it

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the clear explanation! I'm still facing issues (Wrong Answer) with the corrected code.

Comment: I'm editing the above code for better interpretability.